# GWT plugin for netbeans

Tags: netbeans, gwt

I have a project written under GWT. I want to run it in the NetBeans environment, but I can't find the *org-netbeans-modules-gwt4nb.nbm* plugin anywhere.

The link everyone is referring to (`https://gwt4nb.dev.java.net`) is not working.

Can someone tell me where I can get it?